# Mautic emailing - problem with spaces between images

Tags: html, css, mautic

I'm hoping someone will help me. I'm programming an email in Mautic and It's almost done but the main problem I have is that: between two images or image and text is a space and I don't know how to remove it. You can see the whole email code here. I would appreciate any advice how to fix this and have a good looking emailing.

```css
/* Take care of image borders and formatting */
img {
  max-width: 600px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
a img {
  border: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
#outlook a {
  padding:0;
}
.ReadMsgBody {
  width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
  width:100%;
}
.backgroundTable {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  width:100% !important;
}
table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ExternalClass * {
  line-height: 115%;
}
/* General styling */
td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: #e86047;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.force-full-width {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.body-padding {
  padding: 0 75px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
@media screen {
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,900);
  /* Thanks Outlook 2013! */
  body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'sans-serif' !important;
  }
  .w280 {
    width: 280px !important;
  }
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)">
/* Mobile styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  table[class*="w320"] {
    width: 320px !important;
  }
  td[class*="w320"] {
    width: 280px !important;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
  }
  img[class*="w320"] {
    width: 250px !important;
    height: 67px !important;
  }
  td[class*="mobile-spacing"] {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  *[class*="mobile-hide"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
  *[class*="mobile-br"] {
    font-size: 12px !important;
  }
  td[class*="mobile-w20"] {
    width: 20px !important;
  }
  img[class*="mobile-w20"] {
    width: 20px !important;
  }
  td[class*="mobile-center"] {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  table[class*="w100p"] {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  td[class*="activate-now"] {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 20px !important;
  }
  [class="mobile-block"] {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class=" responsejs " style="">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>{subject}
    </title>
  </head>
  <body offset="0" class="body ui-sortable" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: block; background: rgb(238, 235, 235); text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: #000000; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px; cursor: auto; overflow: visible;" bgcolor="#eeebeb">
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0 auto;border-collapse: collapse !important;width: 600px;" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 10px;" data-param-padding-bottom="0" data-param-padding-top="10">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/9b5eae91041367cd39287b92bdb3d3e9.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="38.8594" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse !important; background-color: rgb(0, 124, 220);" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" bgcolor="#007cdc">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-caption-color="129ac7" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" style="text-align: center; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" class="" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/388aa6e28fba0481dad8773fc042558a.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 518px; height: 291.375px;" width="518" height="291.375" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; text-align: center;" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/242f21a049c560ab1395166265f0c254.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 480px; height: 52px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px; max-width: calc(100% - 10px);" width="480" height="52" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" data-param-padding-top="" style="padding-top: 10px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" class="" data-param-padding-bottom="">
                    <h1>
                      ...pĹ™iletĂ­ kdykoliv budete v nesnĂˇzĂ­ch se svĂ˝m marketingem na sociĂˇlnĂ­ch sĂ­tĂ­ch!
                    </h1>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse !important; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-background-color="ffffff" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-text-align="1" data-param-align="1" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/678d01285b77fb587bdb653e5ebcd9d2.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 630px; height: 144.359px;" width="630" height="144.359" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" data-param-padding-top="25" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 2px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <h2>1. NeumĂ­te si spravovat sociĂˇlnĂ­ sĂ­tÄ› a vĂ˝konnostnĂ­ reklamu?
                    </h2>
                    <h3>NevadĂ­! UkĂˇĹľeme vĂˇm, co teÄŹ na sociĂˇlnĂ­ch sĂ­tĂ­ch â€śletĂ­â€ť a nenechĂˇme VĂˇm to uletÄ›t...
                    </h3>
                    <h4>
                      <b>Domluvte si online konzultaci ZDARMA >>>
                      </b>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/491683509f0d67fda7fb2c1c13294381.gif" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="500" height="270" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" data-param-padding-top="25" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 2px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <h2>2. SociĂˇlnĂ­ sĂ­tÄ› vĂˇm jiĹľ spravuje agentura, ale chcete to levnÄ›ji nebo s lepĹˇĂ­m obsahem a vĂ˝sledky?
                    </h2>
                    <h3>Korona VĂˇnoce 2020 jsou za rohem a VY chcete bĂ˝t vidÄ›t! VystĹ™elte s nĂˇmi ke hvÄ›zdĂˇm nebo upadnÄ›te v zapomnÄ›nĂ­...
                    </h3>
                    <h4>Chceme se pĹ™ipravit na VĂˇnoce 2020
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/8b62f9bfeb9fe97ba57cc9c7f4207294.gif" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="500" height="270" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" data-param-padding-top="25" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 2px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <h2>3. MĂˇte skvÄ›lĂ˝ produkt, ale neumĂ­te ho â€śprodatâ€ť na sociĂˇlnĂ­ch sĂ­tĂ­ch?Â 
                    </h2>
                    <h3>UkaĹľme ten vzĂˇcnĂ˝ poklad, kterĂ˝ schovĂˇvĂˇte ve skladu svÄ›tuâ€¦
                      <br />â€śA brzy budete hodnÄ› nÄ›kde!â€ť - Jolanda
                    </h3>
                    <h4>Chceme zaujmout a udrĹľet si #novĂ© zĂˇkaznĂ­ky
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/f0d774b5c8e6e5266520a3a9da2b5106.gif" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="500" height="270" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                    <h2>PojÄŹme se do toho spoleÄŤnÄ› zakousnout!
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                    <div style="text-align: center;">â€žBez strategie jsou sociĂˇlnĂ­ sĂ­tÄ› bezednĂˇ studna na penĂ­zeâ€¦ S tou sprĂˇvnou se stanou vaĹˇĂ­m zlatĂ˝m dolem!â€ś
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 25px;" data-param-padding-bottom="0" data-param-padding-top="25">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/aea055b371bb7e76cc1c7a54ef5e9236.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 625px; height: 141.875px;" width="625" height="141.875" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0 auto;border-collapse: collapse !important;width: 600px;" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/b3dc602ff2dc0093a218d69e6302d700.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="39.0625" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-padding-bottom="0" style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 25px;" data-param-padding-top="25">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/7c9dcd22c754b6c9352d5350fa34dfe4.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="38.8594" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse !important; background-color: rgb(0, 124, 220);" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" bgcolor="#007cdc">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <h2>
                      <b>SkonÄŤete s tou nudou
                        <br />a zaÄŤnÄ›te to s marketingovĂ˝m HRDINOU!
                      </b>
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="button" class="" data-param-float="1" align="center" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-background-color="2ecb71" data-param-link-text="PodĂ­vejte se, co dÄ›lĂˇme jinak?" data-param-button-size="0">
                    <a href="#" class="button" target="_blank" style="border-color: rgb(46, 203, 113); border-width: 10px 20px; border-style: solid; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgb(46, 203, 113); display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 0px;" background="#2ecb71">PodĂ­vejte se, co dÄ›lĂˇme jinak?
                    </a>
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>                                
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; text-align: center; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" data-param-background-color="007cdc" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/31a746de9d24870a515b695106eca718.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 633px; height: 600px;" width="633" height="600" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <center>
        <table data-section="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" class="w320" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: collapse !important;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="force-full-width" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;width: 100% !important;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td data-slot-container="1" style="text-align: center;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;" class="ui-sortable">
                        <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-background-color="ffffff" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                          <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/b5bd5c6bd42ece031ebeab79b8d8a7b6.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 627px; height: 144.375px;" width="627" height="144.375" />
                          <div style="clear:both">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div data-slot="text">
                          <br />
                          <br />
                          <img width="62" height="56" img="" src="https://www.marketingheroes.cz/mautic/themes/sunday/img/gplus.gif" style="max-width: 600px;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
                          <img width="68" height="56" src="https://www.marketingheroes.cz/mautic/themes/sunday/img/facebook.gif" style="max-width: 600px;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
                          <img width="61" height="56" src="https://www.marketingheroes.cz/mautic/themes/sunday/img/twitter.gif" style="max-width: 600px;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
                          <br />
                          <br />
                        </div>
                        <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                          <h3>Chcete vÄ›dÄ›t vĂ­ce... NevĂˇhejte napsat na > <a href="#">chceme@marketingheroes.cz</a> nebo si nĂˇs najdÄ›te na:
                            <br />NovĂ© sady 988/2, 602 00 BrnoÂ 
                          </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                          <a href="{webview_url}">View in browser
                          </a> |  
                          <a href="{unsubscribe_url}">Unsubscribe
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 25px;" data-param-padding-bottom="0" data-param-padding-top="25">
                          <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/f0767d753e853646327c8a1331953ce9.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="141.875" />
                          <div style="clear:both">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0 auto;border-collapse: collapse !important;width: 600px;" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/650aca3949de51ca4c276c92b8beef9e.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="39.0625" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add `margin-bottom:-5px;` to set correctly this white sepration you had and it is fixed properly and worked for all devices.

```css
/* Take care of image borders and formatting */
img {
  max-width: 600px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
a img {
  border: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
#outlook a {
  padding:0;
}
.ReadMsgBody {
  width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
  width:100%;
}
.backgroundTable {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  width:100% !important;
}
table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ExternalClass * {
  line-height: 115%;
}
/* General styling */
td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: #e86047;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.force-full-width {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.body-padding {
  padding: 0 75px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
@media screen {
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,900);
  /* Thanks Outlook 2013! */
  body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'sans-serif' !important;
  }
  .w280 {
    width: 280px !important;
  }
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)">
/* Mobile styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  table[class*="w320"] {
    width: 320px !important;
  }
  td[class*="w320"] {
    width: 280px !important;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
  }
  img[class*="w320"] {
    width: 250px !important;
    height: 67px !important;
  }
  td[class*="mobile-spacing"] {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  *[class*="mobile-hide"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
  *[class*="mobile-br"] {
    font-size: 12px !important;
  }
  td[class*="mobile-w20"] {
    width: 20px !important;
  }
  img[class*="mobile-w20"] {
    width: 20px !important;
  }
  td[class*="mobile-center"] {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  table[class*="w100p"] {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  td[class*="activate-now"] {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 20px !important;
  }
  [class="mobile-block"] {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class=" responsejs " style="">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>{subject}
    </title>
  </head>
  <body offset="0" class="body ui-sortable" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: block; background: rgb(238, 235, 235); text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: #000000; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px; cursor: auto; overflow: visible;" bgcolor="#eeebeb">
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0 auto;border-collapse: collapse !important;width: 600px;" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 10px; margin-bottom:-5px;" data-param-padding-bottom="0" data-param-padding-top="10">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/9b5eae91041367cd39287b92bdb3d3e9.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="38.8594" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse !important; background-color: rgb(0, 124, 220);" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" bgcolor="#007cdc">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-caption-color="129ac7" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" style="text-align: center; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" class="" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/388aa6e28fba0481dad8773fc042558a.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 518px; height: 291.375px;" width="518" height="291.375" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; text-align: center;" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/242f21a049c560ab1395166265f0c254.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 480px; height: 52px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px; max-width: calc(100% - 10px);" width="480" height="52" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" data-param-padding-top="" style="padding-top: 10px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" class="" data-param-padding-bottom="">
                    <h1>
                      ...pĹ™iletĂ­ kdykoliv budete v nesnĂˇzĂ­ch se svĂ˝m marketingem na sociĂˇlnĂ­ch sĂ­tĂ­ch!
                    </h1>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse !important; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-background-color="ffffff" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-text-align="1" data-param-align="1" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/678d01285b77fb587bdb653e5ebcd9d2.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 630px; height: 144.359px;" width="630" height="144.359" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" data-param-padding-top="25" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 2px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <h2>1. NeumĂ­te si spravovat sociĂˇlnĂ­ sĂ­tÄ› a vĂ˝konnostnĂ­ reklamu?
                    </h2>
                    <h3>NevadĂ­! UkĂˇĹľeme vĂˇm, co teÄŹ na sociĂˇlnĂ­ch sĂ­tĂ­ch â€śletĂ­â€ť a nenechĂˇme VĂˇm to uletÄ›t...
                    </h3>
                    <h4>
                      <b>Domluvte si online konzultaci ZDARMA >>>
                      </b>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/491683509f0d67fda7fb2c1c13294381.gif" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="500" height="270" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" data-param-padding-top="25" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 2px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <h2>2. SociĂˇlnĂ­ sĂ­tÄ› vĂˇm jiĹľ spravuje agentura, ale chcete to levnÄ›ji nebo s lepĹˇĂ­m obsahem a vĂ˝sledky?
                    </h2>
                    <h3>Korona VĂˇnoce 2020 jsou za rohem a VY chcete bĂ˝t vidÄ›t! VystĹ™elte s nĂˇmi ke hvÄ›zdĂˇm nebo upadnÄ›te v zapomnÄ›nĂ­...
                    </h3>
                    <h4>Chceme se pĹ™ipravit na VĂˇnoce 2020
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/8b62f9bfeb9fe97ba57cc9c7f4207294.gif" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="500" height="270" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" data-param-padding-top="25" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 2px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <h2>3. MĂˇte skvÄ›lĂ˝ produkt, ale neumĂ­te ho â€śprodatâ€ť na sociĂˇlnĂ­ch sĂ­tĂ­ch?Â 
                    </h2>
                    <h3>UkaĹľme ten vzĂˇcnĂ˝ poklad, kterĂ˝ schovĂˇvĂˇte ve skladu svÄ›tuâ€¦
                      <br />â€śA brzy budete hodnÄ› nÄ›kde!â€ť - Jolanda
                    </h3>
                    <h4>Chceme zaujmout a udrĹľet si #novĂ© zĂˇkaznĂ­ky
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="" class="">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/f0d774b5c8e6e5266520a3a9da2b5106.gif" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="500" height="270" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                    <h2>PojÄŹme se do toho spoleÄŤnÄ› zakousnout!
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                    <div style="text-align: center;">â€žBez strategie jsou sociĂˇlnĂ­ sĂ­tÄ› bezednĂˇ studna na penĂ­zeâ€¦ S tou sprĂˇvnou se stanou vaĹˇĂ­m zlatĂ˝m dolem!â€ś
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 25px; margin-bottom:-5px;" data-param-padding-bottom="0" data-param-padding-top="25">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/aea055b371bb7e76cc1c7a54ef5e9236.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 625px; height: 141.875px;" width="625" height="141.875" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0 auto;border-collapse: collapse !important;width: 600px;" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/b3dc602ff2dc0093a218d69e6302d700.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="39.0625" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-padding-bottom="0" style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 25px;margin-bottom:-5px;" data-param-padding-top="25">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/7c9dcd22c754b6c9352d5350fa34dfe4.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="38.8594" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse !important; background-color: rgb(0, 124, 220);" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" bgcolor="#007cdc">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <h2>
                      <b>SkonÄŤete s tou nudou
                        <br />a zaÄŤnÄ›te to s marketingovĂ˝m HRDINOU!
                      </b>
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="button" class="" data-param-float="1" align="center" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" data-param-background-color="2ecb71" data-param-link-text="PodĂ­vejte se, co dÄ›lĂˇme jinak?" data-param-button-size="0">
                    <a href="#" class="button" target="_blank" style="border-color: rgb(46, 203, 113); border-width: 10px 20px; border-style: solid; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgb(46, 203, 113); display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 0px;" background="#2ecb71">PodĂ­vejte se, co dÄ›lĂˇme jinak?
                    </a>
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>                                
                  </div>
                  <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; text-align: center; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-align="1" data-param-text-align="1" data-param-background-color="007cdc" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/31a746de9d24870a515b695106eca718.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 633px; height: 600px;" width="633" height="600" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <center>
        <table data-section="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" class="w320" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: collapse !important;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="force-full-width" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;width: 100% !important;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td data-slot-container="1" style="text-align: center;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;" class="ui-sortable">
                        <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-background-color="ffffff" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                          <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/b5bd5c6bd42ece031ebeab79b8d8a7b6.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="width: 627px; height: 144.375px;" width="627" height="144.375" />
                          <div style="clear:both">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div data-slot="text">
                          <br />
                          <br />
                          <img width="62" height="56" img="" src="https://www.marketingheroes.cz/mautic/themes/sunday/img/gplus.gif" style="max-width: 600px;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
                          <img width="68" height="56" src="https://www.marketingheroes.cz/mautic/themes/sunday/img/facebook.gif" style="max-width: 600px;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
                          <img width="61" height="56" src="https://www.marketingheroes.cz/mautic/themes/sunday/img/twitter.gif" style="max-width: 600px;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
                          <br />
                          <br />
                        </div>
                        <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                          <h3>Chcete vÄ›dÄ›t vĂ­ce... NevĂˇhejte napsat na > <a href="#">chceme@marketingheroes.cz</a> nebo si nĂˇs najdÄ›te na:
                            <br />NovĂ© sady 988/2, 602 00 BrnoÂ 
                          </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div data-slot="text" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" data-param-padding-bottom="0">
                          <a href="{webview_url}">View in browser
                          </a> |  
                          <a href="{unsubscribe_url}">Unsubscribe
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div data-slot="image" class="" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 25px; margin-bottom:-5px;" data-param-padding-bottom="0" data-param-padding-top="25">
                          <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/f0767d753e853646327c8a1331953ce9.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="141.875" />
                          <div style="clear:both">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div data-section-wrapper="one-column">
      <div data-section-wrapper="1">
        <center>
          <table data-section="1" style="margin: 0 auto;border-collapse: collapse !important;width: 600px;" class="w320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td data-slot-container="1" valign="top" class="mobile-block ui-sortable">
                  <div data-slot="image" data-param-padding-top="0" data-param-padding-bottom="0" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="">
                    <img src="https://marketingheroes.cz/mautic/media/images/650aca3949de51ca4c276c92b8beef9e.png" alt="An image" class="fr-view" style="" width="600" height="39.0625" />
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```